# Buttons with two different function in one form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form name='userForm' ng-submit='addNew(userForm)'>
      <input placeholder='Name' ng-model='userForm.name'/><br>
      <input placeholder='Photo' ng-model='userForm.url'/><br>
      <input placeholder="Phone" ng-model='userForm.phone'/><br>
      <input placeholder="Email" ng-model='userForm.email'/><br>
      <input placeholder="Address" ng-model='userForm.address'/>
      <button type='submit'>Add Contact</button>
      <button ng-click="remove()">Remove Contact</button>
</form>
```

I am trying to do like a simple address book. However, when I try to remove a contact, the remove buttons actually add an empty contact to my list. 
When I move the remove contact line outside the form, it would work just fine.
I assume it is because two buttons are in the same form?
Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Try adding `type="button"` in your remove contact button.

Comment: It works.However, could you explain to me why?

Comment: Actually a button without any type works as submit button inside a form. Thus whenever you were clicking the remove button it was submitting your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add type="button" to your remove button.

Buttons that exist on forms are defaulted to submit types so you should explicitly state that it isn't a submit type.